# google colab tensorflow keras train less examples than needed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, training-data

I am using google colab, and somehow each epoch in the training process is reduced something like 1% of the data.
using:

```
history=model.fit(x=padded_docs,y=y2,validation_split=0.1,batch_size=64,epochs=5)
```

for example, and x.shape is (691058,1)
as you can see from the picture:
[image]

you can also see that 5704 (currently processed examples) can not be divided by the batch size 64, meaning the batch size is not really 64

Comment: Ever considered that that's the number of _batches_ that have been processed? 691058 * 0.9 / 64 rounds down to 9718.

Comment: wow you are right!
but that is not how batch_size suppose to work.
do you have any idea how to make it right?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you mean. Can you explain your question a bit more? BTW sorry if my previous comment came across a bit rude. Reading it now, it sounds like that to me. Wasn't intended that way!